# Discarding a Message within a Spring Integration DSL Service Activator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Is there a way that we can discard a message from within a Spring Integration Service Activator that is defined using the Spring Integration DSL `.handle()` method?

More specifically, assuming the below IntegrationFlow definition...

```
public IntegrationFlow sampleFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
             .from("someChannel")
             .handle(someServiceClass::someMethod)
             .get();
}
```

Is there a way to have a message discarded based on some evaluation within the `someMethod` definition? Ideally, I would like to perform some logging and then discard.

I have found is that returning `null` from `someMethod` seems to effectively end the flow but I am not sure if this is the most graceful/correct solution. If this is the recommended solution, that is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. It is really non-formal pattern to stop processing returning a `null` from the service method. We even have documented it in non-official manner: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#service-activator-namespace

> The service activator is one of those components that is not required to produce a reply message. If your method returns null or has a void return type, the service activator exits after the method invocation, without any signals.

You also can achieve a discard-and-log goal with a `filter()`.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I had a feeling the answer was going to be something along  these lines.